# ASP.NET MVC checkbox validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have multiple asp mvc checkboxes on a form, all with different names, as they are using model binding. I want to be able to use jQuery validation to make sure at least ONE checkbox is checked. But jQuery validation works based on the name of a field, and the names need to be unique for the checkboxes for model binding. How would I use jQuery validation with an asp mvc checkbox group?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662589/unobtrusive-mvc3-validating-group-of-checkboxes

Comment: The only thing I don't see in that solution is how to NOT use an array. I have a list of separate checkboxes with unique names, so I don't know if this will work.

Comment: I would create my own custom attribute server side and and plug in the client-side validation - see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747184/perform-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute). That way you leverage the build-in validation framework on both sides.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: validate form with multiple checkboxes -- at least one must be checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535187/jquery-validate-form-with-multiple-checkboxes-at-least-one-must-be-checked)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. Remember, jQuery can select items or a set of items based on css class or input type, not just by name.

If these are the only checkboxes on the page, you can go:

```
var allboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
if(allboxes.is(":checked"))
{
    //....Do something...
}
```

There's also an example on the [jQuery Checked Selector page](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) that will tell you how to get a count of how many are checked.