# Missing form validation in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form containing only check boxes, and I know that I can make each one required to enforce validation errors. But what I am looking for, is an error if none of the boxes has been checked. How would I go about achieving this?

I am looking for an error message like: "You must select at least one property."

I should clarify that none of the fields are required individually, there should just be at least one chosen option.

---

Edit for clarification:

My view looks something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "id"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
       <div class="col-md-8">
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property1)
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property2)
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property3)
        </div>
     </div>
}
```

My View model looks something like this:

```
public class FormVM 
{
   [Display(Name = "One")]
   public bool Property1 {get;set;}
   [Display(Name = "Two")]
   public bool Property2 {get;set;}
   [Display(Name = "Three")]
   public bool Property3 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: You need to create your own validation attribute. And note that adding the`[Required]` attribute is not necessary unless you want a custom error message - a `bool` is always required

Comment: I realize this, as the bool will always be something, however how do i attach an error message if all of them are false?

Comment: You need to create your own validation attribute :)

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849908/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-for-a-liststring/35952109#35952109) for how you would need to handle client side validation.

Comment: And something similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491521/an-asp-net-mvc-validator-to-make-sure-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked) for the `ValidationAttribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `IValidatableObject` interface on your viewmodel:

```
public class FormVM : IValidatableObject
{
    [Display(Name = "One")]
    public bool Property1 {get;set;}

    [Display(Name = "Two")]
    public bool Property2 {get;set;}

    [Display(Name = "Three")]
    public bool Property3 {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (!(Property1 || Property2 || Property3))
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("You must select at least one property."));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

The benefit of using this is that this will be fired automatically if you call `ModelState.IsValid` in your controller, and the error message added to the `ModelState` errors.

Comment: I am getting an error on the yield.
Also, it says 'No suitable method found to override.'

Comment: Hmm, it's still saying 'No suitable method found to override.' What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added the `IValidatableObject` interface?

Comment: Yup. 
`public class FormVM : IValidatableObject`

Comment: Weird, I can try and help in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112891/missing-form-validation-in-mvc-application

Comment: Figured it out. The `override` was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If this validation is to be used in one place only, then you can validate it in the Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(FormVM model) 
{
    if (!(model.Property1 || model.Property2 || model.Property3))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Property1), "You must select at least one");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

If you are likely to be reusing this validation a lot more, I would suggest writing a validation attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question doesn't mention which server-side or client-side validation were preferred to use, there are 2 approaches.

1) Server-side validation (without ModelState.AddModelError):

Controller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(FormVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // ... other processing code and action returns
    }

    if (!(model.Property1 || model.Property2 || model.Property3))
    {
        ViewData["Error"] = "You must select at least one property." // this can be changed with ViewBag

        // immediately return the same page
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View.cshtml:

```
<p>@ViewData["Error"]</p>
```

2) Client-side validation with vanilla JS, using id to identify required elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var check1 = document.getElementById("check1").value;
var check2 = document.getElementById("check2").value;
var check3 = document.getElementById("check3").value;

if (!(check1 || check2 || check3))
{
     document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You must select at least one property.";
}
else
{
     document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = '';
}
</script>

<div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
       <div class="col-md-8">
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property1, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "check1" })
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property2, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "check2" })
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property3, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "check3" })
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
```